How to implement numeric citations in text with APA 7th edition bibliography with numbered entries in LaTeX using the biblatex?

I would like to achieve the following in my LaTeX document:

Use numeric citation style for in-text citations.
Display the bibliography in APA 7th edition format, but with preceding numeric labels.
The bibliography entries should appear as shown in the attached image (image1), with numeric labels left-aligned and no hanging indent.

I tried the following code, but it didn't achieve the desired result. Currently, the bibliography labels are not appearing correctly, and I couldn't find a suitable solution.
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa,autocite=inline, sorting=nyt,citestyle=numeric-comp,labelnumber=true,defernumbers=true, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0em}

\defbibenvironment{envname}
{\list{\printfield{labelnumber}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{2em} 
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em} 
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-2em} 
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1em} 
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}
        \setlength{\topsep}{\bibtopsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}
    Lorem \parencite{bib1,bib2,bib3}
    \printbibliography[env=shorthand]
%\printbiblist
\end{document}

The bib file
@article{bib1,
  author        = "Campbell, S. L. and Gear, C. W. and Slifka, M. K. and Whitton, J. L.",
  title         = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
  journal       = "Numer. {M}ath.",
  volume        = "72",
  number        = "2",
  pages         = "173--196",
  year          = "1995"
}

%% Journal article with DOI
@article{bib2,
  author        = "Slifka, M. K. and Whitton, J. L.",
  title         = "Clinical implications of dysregulated cytokine production",
  journal       = "J. {M}ol. {M}ed.",
  volume        = "78",
  pages         = "74--80",
  year          = "2000",
  doi           = "10.1007/s001090000086"
}

%% Journal article
@article{bib3,
  author        = "Hamburger, C.",
  title         = "Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of 
                    partial differential equations",
  journal       = "Ann. Mat. Pura. Appl.",
  volume        = "169",
  number        = "2",
  pages         = "321--354",
  year          = "1995"
}


I made some small changes. First, you have to use your environment when calling \printbibliography. Simply replace \printbibliography[env=shorthand] by \printbibliography[env=envname], or change your environment name.
Additionally, you have to set \itemindent to 0em not to -2em.
I also removed \setlength{\topsep}{\bibtopsep}, because bibtopsep seems to be defined as <something>pt but the compiler says, pt is not a unit. Additionally, I did not notice any differences when removing it.
In the end, you should have something like this:
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, sorting=nyt, bibstyle=apa, citestyle=numeric-comp, labelnumber=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0em}

\defbibenvironment{envname}
{\list{\printfield{labelnumber}.}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{2em} 
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{2em} 
        \setlength{\itemindent}{0em} 
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1em} 
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}
    }
}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}
    Lorem \parencite{bib1,bib2,bib3}
    \printbibliography[env=envname]
%\printbiblist
\end{document}

This is the result:


Thank you very much for your help! Your solution perfectly resolved my issue. You mentioned that I have to use your environment when calling \printbibliography, but previously when I tried calling envname, it resulted in errors I wasn't sure how to resolve these errors. However, when I followed your advice and removed\setlength{\topsep}{\bibtopsep}, the issues disappeared. Although I still don't fully understand the reason behind this, I am incredibly grateful for your help. Your modifications perfectly solved my problem. Thank you again!

It should be enough to transplant the definition of the bibliography environment from numeric.bbx (ll. 24-37 in v3.20) to your preamble.
If you don't plan on using other bibliographies with different formats in the same document you need not even choose a new environment name, just stick with bibliography.
To get the dot after the number and not brackets like usual we change the labelnumberwidth field format.
Finally, I cleaned up some of the options (labelnumber=true, autocite=inline, is already set by citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt, selects a generic name-year-title sorting scheme that is subtly different from the name-year-title sorting scheme that bibstyle=apa, selects by default).
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=apa,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  labelnumber=true,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,moraux,aksin,
  companion,westfahl:space,knuth:ct:b,springer}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you very much for your help! Your solution also perfectly resolved my issue.
